# вопрос по Qt, язык C++

Tags: qt4, c++

Каком образом можно сделать так,чтобы при нажатии на клавишу появилось новое окно (новая форма) со своими клавишами,примочками и т.д.Есть Form1 и Form2 их необходимо связать между собой кнопочкой NextButton. Каким образом они связываются? Что прописывается в функции  on_NextButton_clicked() ?Надеюсь, я понятно сформулировала вопрос! :)

Answer (score 1):

Я как то так делал. Создал обьект класса MainWindow (в твоем случае Dialog может быть)

MainWindow m;

m.setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);

m.show();